# Returning a view with previous inputs using Laravel

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I have a form, when submitted, invokes an AJAX request. This ajax request performs back-end validation on the inputs. If an error is detected, it displays the error messages. **So if the user fills out 30 fields, and one is not valid, I would like to return all those inputs with an error message.**

**My Laravel Code:**

```
Route::post('/roa', function() {
$m = Request::except('_token');
$name = "form1_sections/" . $m['nextTab'] . "_form";//next view name
$name2 = "form1_sections/" . $m['currentTab'] . "_form";//current view name

$var= parse_str($m['inputs'], $output);//data from ajax is a string

if ($m['currentTab']=='section2'){//i'm only doing validation on one section right now
//to simplify the code.
    $rules = [
        'TB1_course.*' => 'required'
    ];
    $validator=Validator::make($output, $rules);
    if ($validator->passes()){//if no error, return the next view
        return ["view" => view("$name")-> render(), "value"=>1, "inputs"=>$output];
    }
    return ["view" => view("$name2")->withInput($output)->withErrors($validator) -> render(), "value"=>1, "inputs"=>$output];
}
return ["view" => view("$name") -> render()];
});
```

**My Ajax request:**

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
    var formData = $('#form').serialize();
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/roa',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {inputs: formData, nextTab: relatedTabID, currentTab: tabID},
        success: function(data){
            $('#tabShow').html((data.view));
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('error');
        }
    });
});
```

I am successfully able to receive all the error messages, but the withInput($output) for some reason is not working. Thank you for all your help.

Comment: Can you show us the content of `$output`?

Comment: Sure thing! $output is just an associative array as such:
$output: [
     '_token'=>....,
     'TB1_course' =>[
           '0'=>//user input 1
           '1'=>//user input 2
     ],
     all other inputs
]

Comment: Why would you want that? The fields don't really get erased (unless you explicitly write js that erases them) since you're posting through ajax? But to answer your question - I'm pretty sure that `->withInput()` sets a session flash variable for inputs.

Comment: Since I am replacing the div, where my current view is located, with a view. They would get erased. 
my html looks like:
<div id="tabShow"></div>, and my ajax is replacing all of the html (with inputs) inside of that div with the new view (without inputs)

Answer (score -1):

`'view' => view('template')->withInput()`?

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.